# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) with RNN classifier

Tags: pytorch, valueerror, bilstm

Hello i am having this error while i am trying to train an RNN classifier with pytorch.
I hope someone can help me to fix it or explain me the reason.

```
train_loader2=embeddings_train

train_loader2=torch.from_numpy(embeddings_train)
train_loader2 = DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
y_train=np.array(y_train)
targets2= torch.from_numpy(y_train)

# Initialize network
model = BRNN(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes).to(device)

# Loss and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Train Network
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (dataf, targets2) in enumerate(train_loader2):
        # Get data to cuda if possible
        dataf = dataf.to(device=device).squeeze(1)
        targets2 = targets2.to(device=device)

        # forward
        scores = model(dataf)
        loss = criterion(scores, targets2)

        # backward
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()

        # gradient descent or adam step
        optimizer.step()
```

and this is the error that its occuring

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-d435f4563f2e> in <module>
     15 # Train Network
     16 for epoch in range(num_epochs):
---> 17     for i, (dataf, targets2) in enumerate(train_loader2):
     18         # Get data to cuda if possible
     19         dataf = dataf.to(device=device).squeeze(1)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Why do you define train_loader2 three times? And what is the datatype of train_dataset?

Comment: first of all check type of your object by `type(train_loader2)`, if it's dictionary then use items() if it's not a dict then check the shape .

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers  @Sudhanshu train_loader is a torch.Tensor with shape torch.Size([466, 1024]) and targets2 is also a toch.tensor with shape torch.Size([466, 1]).
I am following a class that i found that used MINST dataset and i want to apply this class to protein embeddings (proteine sequences pretrained with protbert transformer) for binary classification.

Comment: @Kroshtan  check the comment above.

Comment: @Sudhanshu when i used items() i have this error 
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: You are manually assigning to targets2 at the top, and also trying to assign in the for-loop at each iteration. You also didn't answer either of my questions. Your variables are messy and very unclear. I feel like your making a dataloader with just inputs, and have the labels in targets2, so when you try to read the tuple in the for-loop it gives an error, since there is no tuple of (data, labels), but all of that is guess work since your code is a mess.